# How can the ViewModel request an update in the View in WPF/MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a dependency property on a control in my View that is bound to a field on my ViewModel. When the user clicks a menu item I want the control to update the value of that property so the ViewModel can save it in an XML file. What is the correct mechanism to have the ViewModel request that the View update that property?

Answer (score 1):

Generally with MVVM controls update their bound properties (not fields) immediately as they are edited. The ViewModel is the "state", the View is just one way of seeing that state.

Your control should update the ViewModel whenever it is edited. Your ViewModel can then save it to XML when the menu command is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The problem is that fetching the data for the view requires a method call.  This method is not normally called unless the data is needed. The data doesn't get updated automatically when the view is changed.

Comment: Still a bit unclear as to what the exact sequence you want. It's the ViewModel that is responsible for retrieving data. If the view needs to trigger data retrieval at some point then expose a Command to do so in your ViewModel, and invoke it from the view (your menu in the OP?)

Comment: The ViewModel needs to trigger the View to retrieve data from itself. The View has state that needs to be captured with a method call on the control itself when the menu item is clicked and sent back to the ViewModel.

Comment: So the view does not update its bound VM DependencyProperty unless you call a function on the control? Sounds a bit strange, but if that's the case you should be handling it in the view via code behind. The ViewModel should not be aware of implementation details of the view.

Comment: Correct, the view needs to update its property with a method on the control.  

Are saying that the menu item should have code behind that invokes the method on the control that updates the property?

Comment: From the limited info available to me, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that the viewmodel was not updated when clicking on a menuitem right after writing in a TextBox.

With the parameter UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, it worked for TextBoxes:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Room, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

But unfortunately not for DatePickers...

The strange thing is that when clicking on a button instead of the menuitem, the DatePicker is updating the viewmodel. 
As I don't have more time to look for a bugfix right now, I'll just change my menuitems into buttons.

---

Edit: the Problem is not the menuitem but the menu itself. When I move the menuitems out of the menu, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your object must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and your properties should look like this

```
private string _property;
public string Property
{
  get { return _property; }
  set 
  { 
    if(_property == value) return;
    _property = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Property");
  }
}
```

so every change made to the property will be cascaded to view through the binding mechanism.

The menu item command property will be bound to a command declared in the view model and it will trigger a method on view model and set the property value. The change will be cascaded to view:

> menuItem.Click -> menuItem.Command.Execute -> viewModel.method -> change the view model property -> raise property changed event -> view property changed through binding

Comment: I think the OP is asking the opposite. View->ViewModel, not ViewModel->View